# How to find strings in between via Regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like `"(\n    \"FOR SALE\""`, so I need to use regular expression to only catch the FOR SALE value. So I used this regular expression `/\"(.*?)\\/` in `gsub` to catch the string but I don't get any result.

```
"(\n    \"FOR SALE\"".gsub!("/\"(.*?)\\/",'')
```

But I keep getting null result.

Comment: Do you want to match strings surrounded by slashes, backslashes, or double quotes? Your question is not clear at all. The title says slashes, your string has double quotes, and your regex mas backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want whatever is between the first two double quotes, provided there are are at least two, you could do this:

```
r = /
    (?<=\") # match a double quote in a positive lookbehind
    .*?     # match any number of any character, lazily
    (?=\")  # match a double quote in a positive looklookahead
    /x      # define this regex in extended mode

"(\n    \"FOR SALE\""[r] #=> "FOR SALE"
```

Alternatively, you could replace the positive lookbehind with `\K`:

```
r = /
    \"      # match a double quote
    \K      # forget everything matched so far
    .*?     # match any number of any character, lazily
    (?=\")  # match a double quote in a positive looklookahead
    /x      # define this regex in extended mode
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no backslashes in original input. You can use:

```
print "(\n    \"FOR SALE\"".gsub!(/"(.*?)"/, '')
```

**Output:**

```
"(\n    "
```

Or else use:

```
print "(\n    \\\"FOR SALE\\\"".gsub!(/\\"(.*?)\\"/, '')
```

Where `\\\"` will place `\"` in original input.

Answer (score 1):

In double quoted strings, `\"` is the escape sequence for the double quote character `"`, there are not backslash in the original string.

To catch the part between the double quotes, use:

```
"(\n    \"FOR SALE\"".match(/"(.*?)"/)[1]
# => "FOR SALE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work specifically in your case

```
print "(\n    \"FOR SALE\"".match(/\"(.*)\"/)
```

Comment: `puts "(\n NOT FOR SALE AT ANY PRICE".match(/(\w+\s\w+)/)[0] #=> NOT FOR`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> s = "(\n \"FOR SALE\""
> s[/"(.*?)"/m, 1]
#=> "FOR SALE"
```